# squid to speedup authenticated web application

Tags: squid

I want to use a squid to speed up a site with authentication, (user have to login/password on the application first before getting any information).

The slow part of the site are namespaces provide by a rest api:
/api/1/ns_xxx

Does squid allow to serve pages through/after an authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid can totally manage authentication. See the [FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy#Access_to_password_protected_content_fails_via_the_reverse_proxy) from squid. The proper configuration is `login=PASS` at the [cache_peer](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/) level